# Geospatial query doesn't work?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a collection with many document which structure is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a26b07414e7d436786cfe07"),
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -30.0000019073486, 
            25.0000019073486
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "refDate" : ISODate("2017-11-23T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "hourProg" : 0,
    "value1" : 1,
    "value2" : 4
}
```

The range of longitude is [-30; 48]

The range of latitude is [25; 55]

The collection contains about 600,000 records.

I set the 2d_sphere index:  db.myCollection.createIndex({location: "2dsphere"})

If I execute thw query:

```
db.myCollection.find( { 
    location : { 
        $near : {
            $geometry : {
                type : "Point" ,
                coordinates : [-25.27, 25.44] 
            }
        }
    }
}).count()
```

I obtain all records, but I was expecting only a few records (near my coordinates!)

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, the geospatial query with $near get all records ordered in desc mode by distance!

Answer (score 0):

The probable problem is because you do not set the maximum distance.

Inside `find()` function you should have something like this.

```
{
   <location field>: {
     $near: {
       $geometry: {
          type: "Point" ,
          coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
       },
       $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
     }
   }
}
```